# Is it possible to create an unsealed base ref class in Windows Runtime for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

Is it possible to create a base class in Windows Phone 8 variant of Windows Runtime, that other public ref classes can use?

For Windows Store apps [MSDN documents a way to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh699870.aspx) (see below).

However this relies on having `Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject` as an allowed unsealed base class.

As Windows Phone 8 has no C++/XAML programming capability, this class isn't available. You aren't allowed to create a top level object which is visible in public ref classes either as this gives a compiler warning.

Is there another suitable base class that can be used in Windows Phone 8 in place of `Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject`?

```
namespace InheritanceTest2 
{
    namespace WFM = Windows::Foundation::Metadata;

    // Base class. No public constructor.
    [WFM::WebHostHidden]
    public ref class Base : Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject 
       // DependencyObject NOT AVAILABLE ON WP8!
    {
    internal:
        Base(){}
    protected:
        virtual void DoSomething (){}
        property Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty^ WidthProperty;
};

// Class intended for use by client code across ABI.
// Declared as sealed with public constructor.
public ref class MyPublicClass sealed : Base
{
public:
    MyPublicClass(){}
    //...
};
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-049

> WinRT doesn't really support the notion of inheritance for classes. A
>   special case is made for XAML controls in Windows 8, but we don't
>   support C++ XAML on Windows Phone 8.
>
> Peter Torr (MSFT)

Comment: I thought I'd seen this somewhere, but couldn't see it on the MSDN docs. More duplicated boilerplate code around my encapsulated helper class then...