# How to use native classes in Windows Phone runtime component

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, native

I am trying to reuse some c++ code, using a static library.
for example if this is my c++ class in the static library.

```
class testclass
{
   testclass();
   ~testclass();
   void printsomethig();
   void dosomething();
};
```

now i want to inherit this class in my runtime project that later on i want to call it from my windows phone 8 c# project, but the problem is that a native class cannot be public and i can't see the methods and functions if it's not public. for example:

```
public class runtimeTestClass : testclass
{
   runtimeTestClass();
   ~runtimeTestClass();
};
```

The problem is that in runtime native cannot be public (error message), has to be

```
public ref runtimeTestClass sealed
{
    runtimeTestClass();
   ~runtimeTestClass();
};
```

but in this way i cannot inherith anything.

Does anyone know how i can work this out?

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an unsealed base ref class in Windows Runtime for Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296230/is-it-possible-to-create-an-unsealed-base-ref-class-in-windows-runtime-for-windo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would opt to create a WinRT wrapper around your existing class as opposed to using inheritance.

If you delegate all functionality of your `runtimeTestClass` WinRT class to a private instance of your `testclass` then you will be able to use it from c#.